# Fill combobox with XSSFRow

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to fill combobox with row numbers that has been taken from a excel sheet, the problem is I cannot loop row because of combobox.addItem() accepts only string. What other solution would solve this?
the error I got:

```
XSSFRow cannot be converted to String
```

My code:

```
int lastRow = sheets.getLastRowNum();
for (int i=0;i<lastRow;i++){
    XSSFRow row = sheets.getRow(i);
    chooseRowComboBox.addItem(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked with me well:

```
int lastRow = sheets.getLastRowNum() + 1;    
for (int i=1; i<=lastRow; i++){
        XSSFRow currentRow = sheets.getRow(i); 
        if (currentRow != null && currentRow.getCell(0) != null) {
                    chooseRowComboBox.addItem(String.valueOf(i));
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the whole row.. I think you want to get the rownumbers of the filled rows. So you should try something like:

```
public int getNonBlankRowCount(String path) throws IOException{
    File excel = new File(path);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
    XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet sheet = book.getSheetAt(1);
    int rowCount = 0;
    int index = book.getSheetIndex(sheet);
    if(index==-1){
        rowCount=-1;
        return rowCount;
    }
    else{
        sheet=book.getSheetAt(index);
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
        rowCount=0;
        while(rowIterator.hasNext()){
            Row row = (Row) rowIterator.next();
            XSSFCell cell =(XSSFCell) row.getCell(0, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
            if(cell == null){
                break;
            }
            rowCount++;
        }
        return rowCount;
    }
}
```

This method will count ur filled rows. Now u just need to print the returned value into ur combobox like:

```
for(int i=0; i<getNonBlankRowCount("path_to_ur_excel"); i++){
    chooseRowComboBox.addItem(Integer.toString(i)
}
```

If u want to get all rows, you just iterate threw all rows or set 0 < i < 1048577 (the max number of excel rows)